# Overwriting file vs fetching from db

Tags: magento2, database

Can i write over a module js file in Magento 2?

- What are the cons doing it?
- Are there any build in functions that allows me to write to a modules file (I know php allows it).

The problem - I have data in database that I want to use in autocomplete field. The idea is that when the data gets updated in databases then Magento 2 overwrites the file where the array of the file is stored? 
Are there any cons when the array contains about 100+ variables?

**What would demand more resource, fetching data from db with ajax or storing it in a js file?**

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the data in the Database and use a Block Cache to cache the inline javascript data as part of the page HTML.

Then when a user updates the database model (save, delete, etc), you just invalidate that cache... and the next page load for the frontend will regenerate the HTML with the new DB info.