# Magento 2 module file permissions and php file creation functions?

Tags: magento2, php, javascript, permissions, best-practice

**What permissions(rights) should Magento 2 module `files/dir` have in production environment? Can I use php functions that creates a file inside a module directory (fwrite)? I am considering writing db information to `js` file so the module won't make too much db requests. But I am concerned if that might cause any security threats or be against Magento development best practices?**

Background:

I am creating a autocomplete search form and association with that i am considering two options from three (the third that i have sorted out is xml file generation by php):

1. Ajax call from database using `like` when customer types to input
   field.
2. When data has changed in db Cron runs php script that replaces or generates js file from new db information. The file would be located in module directory.

I have asked similar question before, but unfortunately I could not understand the answer what i got. Also i couldn't generate a question to ask that would have made the [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/148687/27598) more clearer for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended file permissions for Magento 2 are explained in the [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html):

- separated web server user and Magento file system owner
- Magento file system owner is in web server group
- Code is only writable by owner
- The following directories are group writable (i.e. writable by the web server user):

  - `var`
  - `vendor`
  - `pub/static`
  - `pub/media`
  - `app/etc`
- additionally, `bin/magento` is executable

Your idea does not work at all if following best practice for the server setup, for several reasons:

- the module directory is either not writable, if it is in `app`, or should only be written by the component installer (composer), if it is in `vendor`.
- `pub` should be the document root, so neither `vendor` nor `app` are accessible from the web. In production mode, files from the `web` directories within a module are *copied* to `pub/static`, so changing those in the module dir would not have any effect either.

Besides that it also does not follow best practices for module development, that is: if you create files that must be accessible from the web, write them to `pub/media`. Magento writes automatically generated files to `pub/static`, but will also happily delete everything it finds there during deployment, so do not use it. As the name suggests, it is meant to be **static**, so it only changes during deployment, not dynamically.

Comment: Thanks! The part where you pointed out the falsity of my idea with point by point was just what I was looking for.